# Somar valores a partir de uma data no Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Tenho uma planilha de excel com duas abas

Aba Cálculo
Aba Valores

Na aba Cálculo tem um campo para colocar a data.

Na aba Valores tem duas colunas uma com o mês e o ano e na outra o valor a ser somado.

Gostaria que quando fosse inserido a data, o excel ache o campo da data e somasse os valores até a presente data.

Tabela Valores

```
Data      Valores

jan/2017  120,00
fev/2017  100,00
mar/2017  80,00
abr/2017  120,00
mai/2017  100,00
jun/2017  80,00
...
out/2019  50,00
```

Quando colocar a data 20/02/2017
O campo deveria achar a data e somar todos os valores.

120+100+80+120+100+80+...+50

Comment: A data que citou aí no exemplo "20/20/2017" não é válida. Deixa eu entender melhor, você quer pegar a data `20 de fevereiro de 2017` e somar todos os valores posteriores a esta data?

Comment: Me desculpe digitei errado, é 20/02/2017. Isso mesmo com essa data, ele acha a celula fev/2017 na planilha valores e soma desde fev/2017 até out/2019

Comment: Supondo que suas datas estejam no intervalo X1:x20, seus valores em Y1:Y20 e sua data em Z1. Utilize: =SOMASE(X1:X20;">="&Z1;Y1:Y20)

Comment: O amigo @anonimo aqui tem razão, a função [SOMASE](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/somase-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-somase-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b) resolve o problema, vou escrever a resposta completa pra facilitar...

Comment: Obrigado anonimo e @Diego Martins, tem como o excel achar a célula pelo valor da data, por exemplo 20/02/2017, ele deveria achar o campo fev/2017

Comment: Depende do conteúdo de sua célula. É uma data simplesmente formatada para ser exibida como mês/ano ou é uma string de caracteres? Em minha sugestão considerei que fosse uma data.

Comment: Testei o função SOMASE, perfeito!!!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o SOMASE()

Simulando que a data de corte esteja na A1 o resultado ficará na A2 e os dados de valor estejam na B4 a B9 e de data na A4 a A9

```
=SOMASE(A4:A9,">="&A1;B4:B9)
```

o resultado ficaria assim:

[image: Resultado Excel]